# Component Property available to all Views Ember?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, ember.js, google-maps-api-3

I want GoogleMap markers and Map object available to all views, is it possible to access google-map component property available to views? or maybe it is a design fault, and someone can suggest a better solution.

Here is the scenario,

1. I have a google map with several markers, which when I hover over
   pops up the infoBox.
2. Now I want this InfoBox to be open whenever
   I hover over the same data outside map.

I have two floating divs, one having GoogleMap and the other having data in it.

Comment: Can you provide a code example? It will be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can;t provide the code sample right now. But let me explain it, suppose you have two divs, one having map and the other having list of markers. If I click or hover on that list, it should show the infoBox, just like this one http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since views will be deprecated in future versions of ember, you should refactor your code to use components exclusively.

Now, if I understand you problem correctly, I think you should use actions to make your 2 components talk to each other (google-maps and infoBox)

What I mean by that is that if you use the controller as an event dispatcher, your 2 components can be connected.

when you click action box, send an action to the controller with appropriate information.

Then when the controller receives the action, dispatch it back to the google-map component through another action.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I achieved what I was looking for. I followed this solution
[GoogleMaps and Ember components respond to actions](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/)
By registering my GoogleMap component as a reference to itself upon initialization, my controller got access to all its (GoogleMap component) actions.